# iPhone MacBook mount for iPhone SE

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, magsafe

I am looking for a clamp to attach my iPhone SE 2022 to my MacBook Pro to be able to use the camera of the iPhone as a webcam with Continuity -- the webcam in the MBP is broken and a repair is quoted at 900 EUR.

I noticed this mount [Belkin iPhone Mount With MagSafe For MacBooks](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/HQ642ZM/A/belkin-iphone-mount-with-magsafe-for-mac-notebooks) however it is specifically to be used with MagSafe-'enabled' iPhones which my SE is not.

I know there are some after-market magnets that I can attach to the phone, such as [the Zagg Snap Adapter](https://eu.zagg.com/snap-adapter?sku=409907724).

Does anybody have experience with adding after-market MagSafe adapters to the iPhone SE, or recommendations for stands/clamps for MacBooks that do not use MagSafe?

Comment: If you can't use MagSafe, then your next option is to use a [clamp style mount](https://amzn.to/47m1SKe). I personally don't like this because if you're going to use this style mount, get a mini tripod instead and use that.  I'm very much against adhering or clamping anything to the LCD panel (cover) of any laptop, much less a MacBook.

Comment: Thanks @Allan - I understand that. However I have a large MBP and a small iPhone SE, I think it will not be too bad. For now I found the [Elephant Card](https://www.elephant-card.com) iPhone clamp. It has the benefit over the other mount options that it's very small. I'll update the post when I used it a little to share how I like it

Answer (score 1):

to answer my own question: I got an 'Elephant Card' mount. It's a small credit-card sized piece of plastic which I can use to 'hang' the phone on the laptop screen. In my opinion, the phone is not too heavy, the card just hangs on the top of the screen, and this will not put stress on the screen.

The Continuity feature makes it easy for the OS to use the phone as a camera.

I've been using this setup for a couple of days now and I'm really happy with the result. I keep the credit-card sized mount in my laptop bag and can use it when I need to, setup is really easy, I do not need to carry additional tripods or whatever, the image quality is much better than the built-in webcam of the laptop and it saves me an expensive repair.